# Changing AUCTeX processor in the file itself

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm using AUCTeX 11.86 in Emacs 23.3.1, under Linux (Ubuntu 12.04.1). Some of my files I compile with LaTeX, a few with XeLaTeX. I'd just like to be able to enter C`-c C-c` to compile, and have the file itself tell AUCTeX which processor to use. Is there a variable I can set in a file which will allow me to do this?

Comment: `M-x add-file-local-variable RET TeX-engine RET xetex RET`

Comment: `M-x TeX-engine-set RET xetex RET` will change the engine for that file regardless of whether any 'engine' variables are set.

Answer (score 8):

You could insert at the end of your `.tex` file:

```
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: LaTeX
%%% TeX-PDF-mode: t
%%% TeX-engine: xetex 
%%% End:
```

and type `C-c C-n` to activate the style change. And next time you open the file in an emacs buffer, the engine will already be set to `xetex`.

[earlier wrong answer replaced by this one provided by [Sean Allred](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/17423/sean-allred) in his comment]

Comment: You can also `C-c C-n` to apply the changes then and there.  Also, `mode: TeX-PDF` works only on technicality; the appropriate lines are `mode: LaTeX` and `TeX-PDF-mode: t`.

Comment: @SeanAllred: replaced my answer by yours!

Comment: Thanks, folks.  In the end I simply added the lines

    % Local Variables:  
    % TeX-command-default: "xeLaTeX"
    % End:

to the end of the file.  This means that when I open the file, the TeX command is automatically set to xeLaTeX.

Comment: @Alasdair I don't think this is the preferred method. Use the `TeX-engine = xetex` method, instead.

Comment: @Alasdair That is, *if* you want to use XeTeX.  See the documentation for `TeX-engine` for a full list of supported values.

Comment: I can see that setting `TeX-engine` to `xetex` would work, but why is that preferred over setting `TeX-command-default` which seems to work perfectly well?

Comment: @Alasdair Because there is no builtin `"xeLaTeX"` command in AUCTeX, I don't know what you talking about.  The way AUCTeX switches between engines is setting the `TeX-engine` variable, not creating new useless commands.

Comment: (Saith the maintainer of AUCTeX.) There may be many things that AUCTeX does that are engine-dependent, and it is the obvious way to check which engine a document expects (for hooks, etc).  Setting the compilation command directly bypasses this and could have unpleasant side-effects, ones that could be avoided be abstracting the command into the idea of a `TeX-engine`. :-)

Comment: @SeanAllred just to be clear: I'm not the maintainer of AUCTeX, just a humble developer `;-)`. The current maintainer is Tassilo Horn (I suppose).  Good point about the engine-dependent stuff!

Comment: @SeanAllred however `C-cC-n` automatically creates an `auto` directory in the current one. I prefer to avoid that [what I do is to save and then `M-x revert`] (in a similar vain, I was quite relieved many years ago when I understood how to stop AucTeX from automatically adding Local Variables lines to any tex file I would open; this was very upsetting, as I like to keep the modification dates of my old tex files unchanged).